# EditText cropping characters while editing

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application for Samsung Galaxy 5 with Android 2.2-update1 that has various EditText fields and I noticed that all EditText fields below the middle of the screen is not repainted correctly when the user is typing: all the characters appear chopped, leaving their half top plain white. I've tested this on other devices and this problem does not happen on them.
Any clues on why this happen and/or any workaround for this for the Galaxy 5?

EDIT: This issue happens with the API Demos that comes with the Android SDK. To reproduce this error execute the demo and then follow: App-> Search-> Invoke Search -> click on App Data and start writing, only the lower half of each character will be rendered on screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in stock applications, or just in an app you are writing?

Comment: @Guilherme MP: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Reuben Scratton: It's an app I'm writing. Tried to look around the Market for an application with the same scenario as mine, I found some close ones but they didn't appear to have this problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I can't post a screenshot since this problem happens only on the Galaxy 5 device, it works fine on the emulator.

Comment: @Guilherme MP: Use DDMS to capture a screenshot from a device.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I just updated my question, it's now also stating how to reproduce it. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: @Guilherme MP: Since you seem to be allergic to screenshots, and since I own no Samsung devices at present, I cannot help you further.

Comment: Just an update on this matter: This problem seems to be a real Android bug. I'm going to post it on the official Android forum. Thanks for all the help.